# Detecting Pre-build/Post-build events

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event, pre-build-event

Is there any way to create a warning message if any Pre-build or Post-build event exists in project, so that another programmer takes into account the external operations while compiling the project.

Comment: What do you mean with "take into account"?

Comment: @stijn I mean to warn another programmer about the external operations (Running batch file, copy files etc.) which exists in Pre-build or Post-build events, without looking at Build Options of IDE.

Comment: Just put `echo "Warning!  Doing something unusual here!!"` in your build event.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this may sound daft.

In your pre-build event check for the existence of a file in your source tree on disk. This file should not be in source control. If the file doesn't exist, pop up a message and either write the file automatically, or prompt your user to do so. If the file exists, do nothing or continue the normal pre-build. This way, new users get the message at least once.

You could use msg to popup a message to the user: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_msg.mspx?mfr=true

.. or powershell
.. or vbscript

Comment: yep. daft. See hans passant's comment on the question. Much simpler.